# Magneto 2 List of logos and images to upload or replace

Tags: magento2

Is there a complete list of logos and images and text required to replace or upload to customize the website,

1. Favicon
2. Header Logo
3. Footer text
4. Welcome text
   Etc

Comment: What you are looking for?

Comment: @Dhiren Vasoya looking for all image files that need to be edited to complete the website.

Comment: are you looking for the place where it can change?

Comment: making a list of all images required for a brand website, so that we can make all the branding images at one go.